# Calculate (SUM) price given from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I would like to calculate the price every choices the user made.
In my database all of these products already have different amount on it.

my Pricelist table looks like this: [Pricelist table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlsZ1.jpg)
*(is this table advisable?)*

I did this because I've wanted to display the amount.
Like this:  [radio button choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3bPP.jpg)

At the same time, my admin can update the price.

I have a bunch of choices need to be calculated and I wanted it to be **Calculated Automatically on the interface**

What I've got so far and working fine.

Above my price I have php like this, **works well**

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db("myrnas", $link);
    $query="SELECT * FROM pricelist";
     $myData = @mysql_query($query, $link); ?>
```

```js
function updateTotal() { 

      var optionprice = 0; //base price to start is 0
    
  function cakeThemePrice() { 
        if (document.getElementById('theme1').checked) {       
            optionprice += 500; }
    
        if (document.getElementById('theme2').checked) {
             optionprice += 200;}
    
        if (document.getElementById('theme3').checked) {
             optionprice += 200; } 
        }
}

  cakeThemePrice();  //function to add them up
  
 var totalPrice = optionprice;
 document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Amount : ₱ " + totalPrice;
```

```html
    
    <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme"  value="wedding" onchange="updateTotal()" />  Wedding 
      <?php
        while($record=mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
        echo "₱".$record['wedding_price'].""; ?> 
    
     <br> <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme"  value="birthday" onchange="updateTotal()" /> Birthday <?php echo "₱".$record['birthday_price'].""; ?> 
    
    <br> <input type="radio" id="theme3" name="cake_theme" value="dedication" onchange="updateTotal()" />Dedication <?php echo "₱".$record['dedi_price'].""; ?>
    <? php } ?>
    
    <span id="totalPrice"> Amount: </span>
```

Well you can see, the price to be displayed is still **hardcoded** , which is I don't want it.
I've seen codes like SUM and putting **data-price** to get the price in my table but I'm not sure how to use it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to automatically compute it via Database (Which is far as I understand) you can do it like this in your query.

```
        <?
          php
          $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
          mysql_select_db("myrnas", $link);
          $query="SELECTcolumn1,column2,SUM(column1+column2)as Sum FROMpricelist";
          $myData = @mysql_query($query, $link); 
    ?>
```

the `Sum` is now a column so it will display in the query like this

```
column1   column2   sum
1         2         3
4         5         9
```

footnote: you may want to use the `mysqli` as because the `mysql` that you are using is deprecated. and may cause trouble for you in the future.

Comment: thank you, but I'm not sure if it will work. Did you check my table structure (1st pic)? I only have 1 row displays the data of each choices (2nd pic). So my price vary depending on the choice. What I'm thinking of your code is that I'll need to **sum all the column** in my table?

Comment: Oh sorry, imgur is blocked in the office. My suggestion is that if you want to just query your result is to use ajax then just add a `WHERE` in my query. :)